# Mac OS: How to draw graph in Mac OS application?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I am developing a Mac OS X application. In that i have to draw a wave graph / chart.
Is there any library / framework available which makes my job easy?
What is the best way of achieving this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) is a plotting framework for iOS and OS X.  I'm not sure if it'll have the exact type of graph you want but it is probably your best bet.

If a web-based API is acceptable then you could look at the Wolfram Alpha API (as @estro suggests) or perhaps the [Google Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Wolfram Alpha API](http://products.wolframalpha.com/api/).